# adb invocation failed do you have adb in your path ? - react native error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Before explaining my question, I would like to tell you what i have tried to solve this issue : 1.setting path file in my .bashrc(ubuntu 16.04)file and even i pasted path command on my terminal but still i am getting same error when i run `react-native run-android` and i came to know about this error by this command : `react-native log-android` . Here is the commands in my .bashrc file : `export ANDROID_HOME=/home/farhan/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

but the above solution didn't work for me, my problem is that hot reloading, live reloading doesn't work properly, most of the time it doesn't get refresh and i have to Control^C and run `react-native run-android` command again and again to refresh the simple changes i made in the code editor. Please let me know the solutions if you have faced this issue or if you have any ideas that may help, please let me know because i have no other choice rather than install ubuntu OS and install everything from scratch to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I believe my problem is solved, the issue was my mobile device and server was not able to communicate properly, how i came to know ? by using this command : `react-native log-android`

If someone is facing the same problem then try this : 
1. Goto https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html then click on "Building projects with native code" then make sure to follow the instructions and set path variables.

2. (this solved my problem) Goto https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device then follow the instructions, i changed the debug server afrom 10.2.2.something to 192.168.(local ip address) now i think both mobile and react-native server are able to communicate properly.

Some helpful commands : 
to refresh and open menu :

```
adb shell input text "RR"
adb shell input keyevent 82
```